# custom visualforce picklist value passing to controller

Tags: visualforce, picklist

Im quite new to salesforce..need a little help.

i want to create a custom picklist in VF page, and then according to the value selected want to render a pageblocktable below on pressing a command button.
This is my code snippet.

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Filter" />
   <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Qualification" itemLabel="Qualification"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Won" itemLabel="Closed Won"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Lost" itemLabel="Closed Lost"/>
            </apex:selectList>
  <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppList2}" var="op2" title="Opportunities">

  <apex:column value="{!op2.name}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!op2.Accountid}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!op2.CloseDate}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!op2.Ownerid}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!op2.Probability}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
```

> controller:

```
public class Opp {


public List<Opportunity> OppList2{get; set;}

string searchquery='select name,accountid,ownerid,closedate,Probability from Opportunity ';

public Opp(){

OppList2=Database.query(searchquery);

}
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated code as below. I have used `<apex:actionSupport` tag to pass the picklist value onchange event. `<apex:actionStatus` is used to provide hint to the user that something is going on in the backend. Hope this will help.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Opp">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Qualification  :  " for="stagename"/>
    <apex:selectList multiselect="false" value="{!filter}" label="Qualification" size="1" id="stagename">
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="--Select--"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Won" itemLabel="Closed Won"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Closed Lost" itemLabel="Closed Lost"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pgbtable" action="{!getresult}" status="status"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    <apex:actionStatus id="status">
      <apex:facet name="start">
        <div>Loading Please wait........</div>
      </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OppList2}" var="op2" title="Opportunities" id="pgbtable">
        <apex:column value="{!op2.name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!op2.Accountid}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!op2.CloseDate}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!op2.Ownerid}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!op2.Probability}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Opp {
    public String filter{get; set;}
    public List < Opportunity > OppList2 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    string searchquery = 'select name,accountid,ownerid,closedate,Probability from Opportunity ';

    public Opp() {
        OppList2 = Database.query(searchquery);
    }
    public void getresult() {
        searchquery = 'select name,accountid,ownerid,closedate,Probability from Opportunity where StageName = :filter ';
        OppList2 = Database.query(searchquery);
    }
}
```

Comment: The given answer is working fine. Thanx for ur help. +1 :)